# Users Can See Folder Without Permissions

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

My users on my network are running on a folder redirect for their desktop.  I want a user to have a folder that only her and the administrators can see; however, when I set permissions for her and administrators, everyone can still see it.

Here's my permissions (both are set to full control):
[image]

Comment: Of course they can see it. The important thing is they can't access it. You might want to look into Access Based Enumeration to see if it's applicable in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks, ABE fixed it!  Can you put an answer in so I may approve it?

Comment: Sure thing. One second...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course they can see it. The important thing is they can't access it. You might want to look into Access Based Enumeration to see if it's applicable in your scenario.